# Polymer.dart 1.0 - The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM

Tags: javascript, json, dart, polymer

I'm working on a hybrid project which combines ASP.NET Core and Dart ([Repo](https://bitbucket.org/Uizz/livereactor/src/bcb4c60939c8d41ce5e1b57d3685a0351ac3c28d/ui/?at=dev)). I use dartson to deserialize my JSON into Dart models, and have also started messing around with Polymer.dart 1.0. After doing loads of plumming and debugging, I have somewhat arrived at a point that can be considered stable (for now). Everything works fine and without any errors in Dartium.

Let me explain my project structure first. I have 2 entry points : `home.html` and `account.html`. I have an `_imports.html` aggregator and have exported my models, services and views as libraries, also aggregated in their speciffic `.dart` files. I use dartson's `@Entity` and `@Property` annotations for mirror-less deserialization when compiling to JS, and Polymer's `@reflectable` to bind to them in my controls.

All good so far, however, when I do a `pub build`, I get the following output :

```
Loading source assets...
Loading initialize/build/loader_replacer, initialize, dartson, web_components, reflectable, polymer_interop/src/build/minify_transformer, reflectable/src/transform_import and web_components/build/mirrors_remover transformers...
Loading polymer transformers...
Unable to spawn isolate: The built-in library 'dart:html' is not available on the stand-alone VM.
'package:polymer/src/template/array_selector.dart': error: line 6 pos 1: library handler failed
import 'dart:html';
^
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart      Isolate.spawnUri.<async>
dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart 34       _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1142                  _RootZone.runBinary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 579            _Future._propagateToListeners.handleError
dart:async/future_impl.dart 641            _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 432            _Future._completeError
dart:async/future_impl.dart 56             _SyncCompleter._completeError
dart:async/future_impl.dart 27             _Completer.completeError
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 439  Isolate._spawnCommon.<fn>
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 148  _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

## UPDATE 2

It looks like my source has nothing to do with it, and that the `dartson` and `polymer` transformers don't like each other. I have created an empty project with an empty `web/` directory and the following `pubspec.yaml`, ran `pub get` and `pub build` and it gives me exactly the same error!

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in `pub` or the Dart VM. I saw similar error messages recently in bug reports. Try updating to the newest Dart version (dev-channel if possible).

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's not that. I've updated to `Pub 1.16.0-dev.5.4` but same error occours. I think it's a Polymer issue because that's where the error is originating from, and also everything seems to work fine if I remove the `polymer` transformer.

Comment: Did you import `@reflectable` on server code or shared code?

Comment: Yes, all my models have `@reflectable` fields. I use it to bind to them in Polymer templates.

Comment: I'm not using `JsProxy` on the server-side, I only use Dart for the front-end part of a website. I have a web API written in C# that returns me JSON, which I deserialize with dartson, and on which I ultimately bind to with Polymer. Everything works fine on Dartium without any erros but I can't `pub build` it because it gives me that error.

Comment: I can't open the repository you linked to in your question (Access denied).

Comment: I've made it private because it's irrelevant - please see my post update.

Comment: The transformers in your `pubspec.yaml` doesn't contain any entry points.

Comment: It's not that either ... Polymer should find the entry points automatically and dartson doesn't need entry points. I did it anyway but it's useless. I'll try comparing the two transformers' source code and see if I find anything. Updated the post again.

Comment: Please change the order of the transformers like `dartson` first, then `polymer`, and `$dart2js` last

Comment: It's not that either. I have chased it down a bit more but that only resulted in further breaking my project, so I have reverted to the latest pre-1.0 Polymer.dart version, as it was the one which worked best for me. Perhaps I will try re-porting when it will be more stable. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I see. The order of the transformers is relevant and I think the order mentioned in my comment above is correct. The root cause of your current problem is then somewhere else thought :-/